# conditional parsing - is it possible?

Tags: gcc, antlr3

I need to implement 2 pass compiler, using same grammar. The 1st pass uses few rules only.The 2nd pass uses the full grammar. I'm looking for flagging which rules are to be used in each pass, something like ifdef ifndef (without extra "noise rules")
Is there an easy way to do that ?

A 2nd question; Is there a way to "trap" EOF and have "Stand By" state at end of file, so the next file (next pANTLR3_INPUT_STREAM ) is smooth continuation of the previous one
What's the best way to implement it ?

thanks

Comment: must be antlr3? antlr4 can optionally turn on/off some lexer rules.

Comment: yes, since it does not support c/c++  targets plus the fact that my grammar is not g4 one

Comment: You are parsing the source text *twice*, one with the full grammar? Why don't you just parse it once, with the full grammar?  Nobody that I know builds a 2 pass-compiler the same way 2 pass assemblers are built, which is what it sounds like you are doing.

Comment: Hardware module instantiations are parameterized so it make sense (brute force solution) to order the reading in of  the source files top down

Comment: The point is that if you have to *touch* the file at all to decide if you need it, you might as well parse it; its already in your hands.  You won't save any time by full-parsing it later.  You can always delay processing the parsed file (assuming you build a parse tree, otherwise I have no clue how you are going to any kind of interesting "compilation") by simply hanging on to the AST until it it is needed.   Memory's cheap;  you can't overwhelm it these days with source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use semantic predicates to allow the parser to follow certain paths like this:

```
remove_partitioning:
    {SERVER_VERSION >= 50100}? => REMOVE_SYMBOL PARTITIONING_SYMBOL
;
```

I used this all the time to enable/disable version dependent language features.

SERVER_VERSION is a macro that I define in the @lexer::includes section:

```
#define SERVER_VERSION ((RecognitionContext*)RECOGNIZER->state->userp)->version
```

As you can see I use the recognizer state's user pointer to pass in a structure that carries context information for the parser and lexer. This value is set when the parser is created:

```
...
_lexer = MySQLLexerNew(_input);
_lexer->pLexer->rec->state->userp = &_context;
_tokens = antlr3CommonTokenStreamSourceNew(ANTLR3_SIZE_HINT, TOKENSOURCE(_lexer));
_parser = MySQLParserNew(_tokens);
_parser->pParser->rec->state->userp = &_context;
...
```

Comment: thank you Mike. It's a nice solution but i'm not sure it's applicable for me. The reason is that if i eliminate parser rule i'll get error. If I'm correct in your case you disable rules for illegal input. In my case I have the very same data ..just i want to ignore certain rules ... Possible alternative is to consume whole rule - do that conditionally (1st pass) however i don't see a way to consume until end of rule.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. Something like code between #ifdef and #endif if the condition is false. So, what you actually need is not to ignore some rules in the first run but some input. If you have specific start and end tokens you can a rule similar to the usual multiline /* ... */ which is also able to skip anything in it.